# Xcode - many windows

Tags: xcode, window

I have a confusing problem in Xcode.

The problem occures only in a single project and started about few days ago (don't know what caused it).

I need to see many parts of code in different files to code something, so I just double click a file from the Xcode's sidebar and it opens in a new Xcode window (a little bit simplified then the main window).

When I do the same with the next file, the next window is shown (so I should have three windows now), but in this project it's not. The previous window is replaced with the title and content on new file.

It's really annoying - I even can't see at once the localization file, and the both .h and .m file of the class I'm working on.

Does anyone knows a solution? I repeat - it's only in this project - in the other project it works fine.

I have the 3.2.5 version, but it was present in previous as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you open the new window click on the group/ungroup button at the right hand top.  This will solve your problem.